# Firebase, relogin automatically usin REST services

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for authentication, by calling REST endpoint with email/password.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[API_KEY]
```

If user exists in database, I receive a json of following format:

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
  "localId": "ZY1rJK0eYLg...",
  "email": "[user@example.com]",
  "displayName": "",
  "idToken": "[ID_TOKEN]",
  "registered": true,
  "refreshToken": "[REFRESH_TOKEN]",
  "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

Right after that, I want to automatically re-login when I am opening app again. 
As far as I understand I need to use for that Sign in with OAuth credential from Firebase API(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential)

But, I cant understand what parameters I should use to do that, taking into account my initial email/password login.

API accepts following:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"postBody":"id_token=[GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN]&providerId=[google.com]","requestUri":"[http://localhost]","returnIdpCredential":true,"returnSecureToken":true}'
```

What should I use for GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN, providerId  and requestUri?
Have I received anything in my first login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing Firebase ID tokens with Google ID tokens.
After the user logs in via verifyPassword, you store locally the refreshToken and the idToken. You need the idToken for authenticated access to restricted resources like Firebase Database, etc. The idToken will expire after some time, typically one hour. You use the stored refreshToken to get a new idToken via: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-refresh-token

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yea, you are right, seems like I missed a lot. What I want to reach is the behavior - user logins once. Then he receives the token that is valid for lets say 2 weeks. And on every app opening after, we validate that token with server, checks is that still valid. If yes - proceed to an app. if no - ask to login once again. Is that something that Firebase can do with its REST API?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Firebase Auth sessions are indefinite. On sign-in, you get 2 types of tokens: a short lived one hour ID token and a long lived refresh token. The latter can be used to get new ID tokens. If you want to reject tokens older than 2 weeks, you can check the auth_time in the ID token JWT. If it is older, you can force reauthentication on the client side.